# Conditional printf for STM32L0 MCU in IAR IDE

Tags: c, debugging, ide, printf

I use IAR ide in order to create `blinking LED app` ("Hello world" for MCU). It works fine under debugger, but after downloading *.bin file using ST-LINK utility, no blinking occurred. I've commented out all calls to `printf()`, then it succeeded. I've found the workaround:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
  #define PRINTF(a) printf a  
#else
  #define PRINTF(a) (void)0
#endif
```

But NDEBUG is not defined in Release configuration. How can I fix it? I mean options dialog usage, not polluting source file with #define NDEBUG.

Comment: *"But NDEBUG is not defined in Release configuration. How can I fix it? I mean options dialog usage, not polluting source file with #define NDEBUG."* That paragraph makes no sense. Please [edit] and clarify what the problem is.